# Having trouble using jsmile with ColdFusion

Tags: java, coldfusion

Running ColdFusion 10g on Windows.

I am trying to integrate a fairly simple java app written using jsmile but I can not get it to work under ColdFusion.

jsmile requires a DLL (cleverly named jsmile.dll). It runs on the command line, but when I try to get it running under CF I get:

```
*java.lang.UnsatisfiedLinkError: no jsmile in java.library.path (error at the first line where it tries to invoke the smile.Network)*
```

I have added the specific path to the `javaVM using -Djava.library.path=PATH_TO_DLL`.
I have copied the DLL to somewhere in the Windows Path (tried moving it to different directories in the path).
I have copied the path to the DLL to the Windows Path variable.
I have tried using `System.setProperty("java.library.path", "PATH")` in my code.
I have tried using `System.load("PATH")` in my code before the lines invoking smile.

I shutdown/restart the ColdFusion service after each attempt but I always get the same error. I have even tried shutting down the server with no improvement.

Any help would be appreciated... pulling my hair out here... :-/

Comment: What is the exact value of the paths above? A quick search suggests `java.library.path` should be a directory, not a path to the actual file. Also [this thread mentions](http://www.coderanch.com/t/377174/java/java/java-library-path) that the `UnsatisfiedLinkError` is sometimes misleading. It can also indicate a problem loading the library, rather than a problem locating the physical file.

Comment: Yes, I caught the directory, not full path issue (only after trying the full path a few times). I will check out the problem loading the library. Maybe the DLL is incompatible with the JVM...

Comment: Well it is hard to get a handle on your setup without seeing the actual paths and values you have tried. It would help to post them (including the dll).. or at least examples accurately representing the paths.  The docs mention it is 32 bit only.  Is your JVM 32bit?

Comment: I scanned the drive and can verify that there is only one copy of jsmile.dll, it is 32bit on a 32bit server and that at the moment it is not in the windows path. jsmile.dll is in the directory: `C:\wwwroot\trivial\java\RAP_Likelihood_Scoring\lib\win32`. I added `-DC:\wwwroot\trivial\java\RAP_Likelihood_Scoring\lib\win32` to the JVM arguments under the CF Admin page.

Comment: Here is the specific error I am seeing in ColdFusion as of the most recent run: `java.lang.ClassCastException: java.lang.UnsatisfiedLinkError cannot be cast to java.lang.Exception
 at coldfusion.runtime.java.JavaProxy.CreateObject(JavaProxy.java:169)
 at coldfusion.runtime.java.JavaProxy.invoke(JavaProxy.java:80)
 at coldfusion.runtime.CfJspPage._invoke(CfJspPage.java:2483)
 at cfindex2ecfm1643775901.runPage(C:\wwwroot\trivial\index.cfm:8)`  index.cfm is the page trying to use java app.